# SQL: .. contains an unresolved reference to an object

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

Full message

```
Parameter: [DbName].[SpName].@timeout contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [dbo].[TIME]
```

I know, there is couple of Question already exists with this message. But this one in my example happens especially because of TIME Sql type.

I Have StoredProcedure ( in Visual Studio Sql Database project ) which is looks like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_sp] 
   @name VARCHAR(255),
   @timeout TIME 
AS
  ...
```

I have no any table with name **TIME**. When I change the type TIME with other, it stars work correctly, other way it shows this message in TIME type and compile time error.

TIME I trying to use as a SQL alternative for C#'s TimeSpan.

Comment: What SQL Server version is this? `time` was introduced in 2008, IIRC - note, it is also `time`, not `TIME` - so ... case sensitivity problem perhaps? Personally I'd be cautious of using `time` as `TimeSpan` - they don't mean quite the same thing and have very different ranges and precisions

Comment: SQL Server 2005 has been unsupported for coming on three years - https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/sql-server/sql-server-2005 . Might be time to look to upgrade...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `time` with SQL Server 2005, since it didn't exist until SQL Server 2008.

Instead, consider storing a numeric representation of the time interval (which is, ultimately, what `time` is *anyway* - just: you'd be doing it explicitly rather than automatically). Typical examples would be to store, as an `int`, the number of seconds or milliseconds represented by your time interval.

Conveniently, `TimeSpan` has a `TotalSeconds` and `TotalMilliseconds` property that maps to this (just: convert it to an integer),  and has `FromSeconds(...)` and `FromMilliseconds(...)` methods for going the other direction.

---

From comments, it sounds like you also need features to combine (add) times to dates; this is also easy:

```
DATEADD(second, {interval as seconds}, {some datetime})
```

or

```
DATEADD(millisecond, {interval as milliseconds}, {some datetime})
```